# Polyfill for bind includes using call or apply, why?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

The polyfill of bind which I find online is something like -

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(obj, ...args) {
  const self = this;
  return function(...args2) {
    return self.apply(obj, [...args, ...args2]);
  };
}
```

where we use call/apply to call the function.

My question is why not simplify it to be

```
Function.prototype.myBind = function (obj, ...args) {
  obj.func = this;
  return function (...params) {
    return obj.func(...args, ...params)
  }
};
```

because internally both `call` and `apply` assign the function to the object and then execute it.

Comment: What if the provided context (`obj`) is not actually an object? The proposed method would fail for any scalar value. It also mutates the context object by setting the `func` property, which I would not expect as the user of `.bind`. What if the provided object already has a `func` property?

Comment: That isn't a polyfill for `Function.prototype.bind` (ES5) because it contains the spread operator (ES6) which cannot be polyfilled and doesn't work in pre-ES5 environments. To properly polyfill `Function.prototype.bind` you have to use code that runs in pre-ES5 JavaScript environments. Use the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 2):

By doing

```
obj.func = this;
```

you are mutating the object passed in. `.bind` does not do such a thing, and it's almost always a good idea not to mutate objects that you don't "own" (that is, are only used by your own internal code).

It would be quite strange for a call to `.bind` result in a mutation of an object which may be completely unrelated to the caller, eg:

```js
Function.prototype.myBind = function (obj, ...args) {
  obj.func = this;
  return function (...params) {
    return obj.func(...args, ...params)
  }
};

const obj = {
  foo: 'foo'
};

function fn() {
  console.log(this);
}
const boundFn = fn.myBind(obj);
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

It's much safer and predictable to avoid side effects and keep the bound function inside `.bind`'s closure than to set it on an external object which isn't expecting a new property to suddenly appear on it.

As for the title:

> Polyfill for bind includes using call or apply, why?

IIRC, `.bind` was introduced in ES5. But `.apply` exists in ES3 too, and since basically all environments anyone uses are at least ES3, using `.apply` to polyfill `.bind` is safe. (though. using spread/rest syntax is not, since that's ES2015)